# Accessing layers offered by an ArcGIS REST Server via Python Console?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, arcgis-server, layers

Vindbrukskollen has [a nice map of wind turbines](https://vbk.lansstyrelsen.se/). From the source of that webpage, I get this link to an ArcGIS REST Server Layer:

https://ext-geodata-nationella.lansstyrelsen.se/arcgis/rest/services/

In QGIS, I click on `Layer -> Add Layer -> Add ArcGIS REST Server Layer -> New`, then privde this URL and give a name to the layer. After `OK`, I `Connect` to the layer. I am offered to choose from a lot of layers:

[image]

Layers seem to be organised into folders. I opened a few to show that there are many. In some cases, the file structure is even deeper:

[image]

If I add all of them, my QGIS session crashes. I don't want to manually copy-paste all of them. After clicking `Plugins -> Python Console`, I am able to access layer names of already added layers, that is described in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/340288/191643).

**How can I use Python Console to access the name of layers offered by the REST Server, before adding these layers to canvas?**

In other words: I need to access to the dropdown list shown on the above screenshot via Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a script that will walk through the directory of folders, services, and layers. Ultimately, it prints the folder name, the service name, the layer name, and layer type for all available layers.

See [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/422248/128665) for clarification on how the URLs were derived.

```py
import urllib.request, json 

root_url = r'https://ext-geodata-nationella.lansstyrelsen.se/arcgis/rest/services/?f=pjson'

# download the root json
with urllib.request.urlopen(root_url) as url:
    data = json.loads(url.read().decode())


# iterate through the 'folders' key of the root json
for folder in data['folders']:
    
    # construct a url to get the json of the folder
    folder_url = root_url.split('?')[0] + folder + '?f=pjson'
    
    # download the folder json
    with urllib.request.urlopen(folder_url) as url:
        sub_data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
    
    # some urls require a log in, in which case the json has a key called 'error'
    if 'error' not in sub_data.keys():
        for service in sub_data['services']:
            
            # construct the url for the service json
            service_url = folder_url.split(folder)[0] + service['name'] + '/MapServer/?f=pjson'

            # download service json
            with urllib.request.urlopen(service_url) as url:
                sub_sub_data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
                
            # iterate through service json 'layers' key
            for layer in sub_sub_data['layers']:
                
                # do something with results
                print(folder, '|', service['name'], '|', layer['name'], '|', layer['type'])
```

Sample of output (the whole output is very large).

```
BS | BS/lst_bs_mov03 | BS Förbudsområde 1-årsregeln | Feature Layer
BS | BS/lst_bs_mov03 | BS Beviljade bearbetningskoncessioner | Feature Layer
Energimyndigheten | Energimyndigheten/lst_energigas_fak09 | Fordonsgasinfrastruktur (grupp) | Group Layer
Energimyndigheten | Energimyndigheten/lst_energigas_fak09 | Tankställen för flytande fordonsgas | Feature Layer
Energimyndigheten | Energimyndigheten/lst_energigas_fak09 | Tankställen för fordonsgas | Feature Layer
FHM | FHM/lst_fhm_fak02 | FHM Badplatser (alla) | Feature Layer
FM | FM/lst_fm_riksintressen_3_9 | FM_Riksintresse_pa_land_MB3kap9 | Feature Layer
FM | FM/lst_fm_riksintressen_3_9 | FM_Riksintresse_i_havet_sjoovningsomrade_MB3kap9 | Feature Layer
```